# Uploading Node_Modules on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I would like to know the procedure for uploading node_modules onto Google App Engine.

Comment: How do you update the rest of your code?

Comment: @FelipeSabino, I run `gcloud app deploy` at the moment, I am using CDN JS to load because nothing from `node_modules` is being accepted.